# how to assign content type to different form data fields?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm supposed to work with an API that receives json and files as multipart form data as shown in this postman screenshot
[image]

i have no issue creating a formData object and appending the data and the files to it, but when i send the request, i keep getting an error with status code 415 which is related to wrong content type assigned. i made sure that the request header content type is set to multipart formdata. so i think the issue is happening because the content type of the fields themselves is not matching the expected type on the BE

how can i set a content type property to each field in the formData object?

```
      let fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(jsonBdoy))
      //documentFiles is array of file objects
      //content type of each file is different based on the file itself, and doesn't match the required
      documentFiles.forEach(doc => {
        fd.append("documents", doc)
      })
      const res = await this.$axios.$post('/myApiRoute', data)
     // result error status code 415
```